# How to restrict access to untrusted code in Twig include function with sandboxing

Tags: php, twig, sandbox

As not expected I'm able to access non-witelisted functions.

Policy config:

```
$policy = new \Twig\Sandbox\SecurityPolicy(); // should disallow all
$sandbox = new \Twig\Extension\SandboxExtension($policy);
$twig->addExtension($sandbox);
```

Twig template:

`{{ include(template_from_string(data), sandboxed=true) }}`

where *data* contains the external code beeing restricted:

```
{% if totalAmount %}
    total: {{ totalAmount|number_format }}
{% endif %}
```

As I understand the not very detailed docs, I shouldn't have access to either **if**, **totalAmount** and **number_format**. How to restrict that?

Answer (score 0):

To enable a global sandbox mode u'd need to pass `true` as the second argument of the `SandboxExtension` constructor otherwise you'd need to use the `{% sandbox %}`-tag in places where you don't trust the code that is ran.

```php
$policy = new \Twig\Sandbox\SecurityPolicy();
$sandbox = new \Twig\Extension\SandboxExtension($policy, true);
$twig->addExtension($sandbox);
```

---

```html
{% sandbox %}
    {% include(template_from_string(data) %}
{% endsandbox %}
```

Comment: thx for the reply. Global sandboxing is no option for me, because all other coder around the provided is trusted.

Comment: your 2nd solution crashes with **Only "include" tags are allowed within a "sandbox" section.**, even when I whitelist the **include** function.

Comment: Well yeah, because you didn't add the tag `if` to the whitelist? You have to update your [policy](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/1.x/api.html#sandbox-extension)

Comment: The above error appears even if the template is empty